# Support needed creating Dovecot listener on Debian ( postfix)

Tags: postfix, dovecot, chroot, listener

I would like to create a dovecot lmtp listener under /var/spool/postfix/private/.
Because postfix runs chrooted by default under debian.

How can I do this?

Grtz

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this. LMTP is a network protocol that uses TCP/IP for data exchange. What you describe is a Unix socket, but this is not applicable for LMTP.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary with [mailq answer](https://serverfault.com/a/324354/218590), actually you can do it via Dovecot version 2.0 released at August 2010. The documentation can be found here: [Postfix and Dovecot LMTP](http://wiki2.dovecot.org/HowTo/PostfixDovecotLMTP). To preventing link-rot answer, here the summary of that page

In debian postfix run with chroot, so you need place LMTP socket in postfix queue directory (usually in `/var/spool/postfix/` directory). So in dovecot set the LMTP service like this

```
service lmtp {
 unix_listener /var/spool/postfix/private/dovecot-lmtp {
   group = postfix
   mode = 0600
   user = postfix
  }
}
```

The final step is to tell Postfix to use this socket for final delivery, in this case in a virtual user scenario:

```
virtual_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```

For a non virtual user setup ( as when mail_location = maildir:~/.maildir ) :

```
mailbox_transport = lmtp:unix:private/dovecot-lmtp
```